# MacBook Air (Liquid Spill)

Tags: macbook-pro

About 2 years ago I had a liquid spill on my MacBook Air 2015 model. It shut off back then and completely stopped working. I didn’t want to throw it away so I kept it and I guess it’s been air drying ever since. I randomly decided to plug it in last night and it actually charged and turned on. I was able to log in on it. I messed up when I tried to reset the guest account thinking it would do something different. And now I see this screen with I guess the side of a computer. I’m just trying to reset it to factory settings.

Comment: What does this mean? "And now I see this screen with I guess the side of a computer."

Comment: I wasn’t able to upload the photo due to size issues.

Comment: It flashes between two photos. One looks like the side of the laptop and the other a mouse of some sort

Comment: That sounds like the "Please plug in a keyboard & mouse" screen, usually seen on desktops… but a photo would halp.

Comment: Is there a way I could send it to you via email? If you don’t mind